# Get point between two points crossing the 180 degree meridian at 180 degrees

Tags: coordinates, latitude-longitude, mapbox-gl-js, calculation

I am plotting a line on a MapboxGL (js) world map that follows the path of orbital objects. I do this by adding a new set of decimal longitude/latitude coordinates to a line geometry array as the orbit of the object updates.

There is a known issue with Mapbox (and others) that when drawing a line that crosses the 180° meridian (longitude), we do not get a nice straight line from a to b, we get a very long line that wraps around the whole globe from a to b:

```
instead of:  we get:
     /             /
    /             /___
.../.....    ......... 180° meridian 
  /          ___
 /             /
/             /
```

"Accepted" answers here and at Mapbox suggest shifting to a 0°/360° longitude range, but this just moves the problem from the equator to the pole. This is fine for most general proposes, but is still an issue for orbital tracking where we may be crossing the 0°/360° meridian.

My solution is to use MultiLine geometry and break up my coords into new arrays when I cross this meridian, however, this will always leave a wee gap, or, if I "180, lat" either side, we get a "kink" at the meridian:

```
gap:        or kink:
     /            /
    /            /
........    .....|...  180° meridian 
                /
 /             /
/             /
```

So I need to figure out what the *exact* latitude would be if the longitude is on the meridian, knowing the start and end points either side:

```
 +170  |     p2 /: 
       |       / : 
       |      /  : 
  180 -|-----/ pX? --  180° meridian 
       |    /:   : 
 (lng) |   / :   : 
       |  /  :   : 
 -170  |_/___:___:___
        p1   x?  
          (lat)
```

I need to solve for latitude x so I can generate pX (knowing p1 and p2 if longitude where 180). Once I have pX, I can add this to the end of the last line and to the beginning of the next, thus closing the gap (or smoothing the "kink").

I know this is basic Trig, but my old-man-brain has failed me .. again ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! With basic Trig (while writing the question - so I am posting it anyway, just incase it helps someone else):

We are basically playing with two right triangles: p1 to p2, and the smaller right triangle where the opposite side stops at the meridian, both with the same hypotenuse angle. So, we have:

```
 +170  |     p2 /| 
       |       / | 
       |      /  | 
  180 -|-----/ pX? --  180° meridian 
       |    /:   | 
 (lng) |   / : A | 
       |  / B:   | 
 -170  |_/___:___|___
        p1   x?  
          (lat)
```

Where A is our p1 to p2 right angle triangle and B is the triangle from p1 longitude to the meridian, whose adjacent side we need to work out.

Pythagoras basically teaches us that all we need is two points of data (other then the right angle) of a right triangle to solve any other.

We already have the opposite and adjacent lengths of A:

```
 +170  |     p2 /| 
       |       /α| 
       |      /  | 
  180 -|--   /   | --  180° meridian 
       |    /    | 
 (lng) |   /  A  | oppositeA
       |  /      | 
 -170  |_/β______|___
        p1  adjacentA     
          (lat)
```

So from here we need to calculate the hypotenuse of A to get the *angle* of the hypotenuse of A (α) so we can use it later:

```
// add 360 to a negative longitude to shift lng from -180/+180, to 0/360
p1 = { lng: p1.lng < 0 ? p1.lng + 360 : p1.lng, lat: p1.lat }
p2 = { lng: p2.lng < 0 ? p2.lng + 360 : p2.lng, lat: p2.lat }
let oppositeA = Math.abs(p2.lng - p1.lng) // get A opposite length
let adjacentA = Math.abs(p2.lat - p1.lat) // get A adjacent length
let hypotenuseA = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(oppositeA,2) + Math.pow(adjacentA,2)) // calc A hypotenuse
let angleA = Math.asin(oppositeA / hypotenuseA) // calc A hypotenuse angle
```

Now we need the *new* opposite of B (p1.lng to 180) and our calculated angle of A to work out the new hypotenuse of B so we can get the new *adjacent* of B:

```
 +170  |     p2 /  
       |       /   
       |      /    
  180 -|--   /     --  180° meridian 
       |    /: B    
 (lng) |   /α:     
       |  /  : oppositeB
 -170  |_/___:___ ___
        p1  adjacentB
          (lat)
```

```
let oppositeB = Math.abs(180 - p1.lng) // get B opposite
let hypotenuseB = oppositeB / Math.cos(angleA) // calc B hypotenuse using A angle
let adjacentB = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(oppositeB,2) + Math.pow(hypotenuseB,2)); calc B adjacent
```

Now we add the new adjacent to p1 latitude, and we have x! So:

```
let pX = { lng: 180, lat: p1.lat + adjacentB }
```

End the last line array and start the next with pX, and the gap is perfectly closed!

Highschool math (well, the genius of Pythagoras) to the rescue! I knew it was rattling around in that old-man-brain somewhere .....

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to split a line in this way would be to use Turf's [`lineSplit`](http://turfjs.org/docs/#lineSplit) function. Something like:

```js
const meridian = turf.lineString([[180, -90], [180, 90]]);
const linePieces = turf.lineSplit(myline, meridian);
```

I haven't tried this, so not sure if Turf itself has any weirdness at the meridian. If it does, you might have to temporarily translate the coordinates elsewhere or something.

Better than doing your own trigonometry in any case, especially since it may introduce errors with the world not being flat.

Comment: Thanks! I had not seen turf.js before! I am loath to load an entire lib for a single calc, but it may be worth it if basic Trig gives me bad results at high zoom (assuming the lineSplit method does not invoke weirdness at the meridian too!).

I realise the world not being flat, or indeed not a perfect sphere (what with our spin making us a bit chubby in the middle), means I might be a bit off, especially at the equator , but for the scales I am working with, "close enough appears good enough" .. so far... I will give it a go and report back.

Comment: I gave turf a go, and unfortunately lineSplit and lineIntersect returned empty feature arrays. I think it is a bit buggy as even cutting and pasting their examples returned empty. For the record, my Trig attempt produces a small kink at the equator, but it is only out by a handful of meters. It seems perfect at the poles. This is more than good enough for me, and the Trig is relatively low cost!

Comment: Correction: turf.lineIntersect works from version 6.5.0 on, but is also cursed with the "world is not flat" issue. Zoom in on the docs example and you will see the position error. If you look at the source, they are using Cartesian coordinates, not spherical. I get the same "precision" with raw Trig :P There are examples online of some scary math to correct for spherical, but close enough is good enough for me :D